# Как правильно писать коммиты?

Tags: c++, git, github

Есть проект на достаточно много файлов(.cpp и .h проект на C++).
В общем решил я использовать git. Я залил весь проект на гит, мне что каждый файл комитить?
То есть сидеть и описывать каждый файл?
И как правильно писать коммиты?

Comment: коммитте изменения в проекте - если изменение это просто добавление одного файла, то коммитить этот файл

Comment: если вы имеете в виду сообщение комита, то там необходимо описать сделанные в данном комите изменения. Один комит может включать сразу несколько файлов, объединенных одной логической задачей.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В каждом коммите может быть несколько файлов. В вашем случае, когда вы загружаете в git готовый проект, принято добавлять все файлы с комментарием **Initial commit** или с подобным.

В дальнейшем вы сами выбираете политику добавления. Можно, скажем, решить задачу целиком и зафиксировать все изменения. Такая практика считается не очень удобной для последующих разборов, поскольку в каждом коммите оказывается слишком много файлов.

Есть подход т.н. *микрокоммитов*. Вы решаете часть задачи, покрываете её тестами, у вас всё компилируется — самое время зафиксировать изменения. Обычно в таком коммите не очень много файлов.

Если вдруг вы видите, что имя метода не очень хорошо описывает его работу, вы можете его переименовать. Это *рефакторинг* в который может попасть много файлов, потому что метод может вызываться из десятков мест. Его тоже оформляют одним коммитом.

Есть и промежуточный подход, когда в одном коммите у вас может оказаться несколько решённых подзадач. Если команда не возражает, то этот способ тоже подходит.

Пофайловая фиксация не привносит дополнительного удобства. Лучше коммитить, когда вы чувствуете, что завершили очередной этап решения задачи.

#### Комментарии

К коммиту обязательно надо писать комментарии. Бывает, что люди пишут троеточие, чтобы комментарий не был пустым.

Это не очень хорошо. Обычно рекомендуют кратко (до 50-ти символов) описать суть решённой подзадачи. Так можно облегчить последующий разбор.

Если в 50 символов не укладываетесь, делайте короткий заголовок, пустую строку, и затем пишите уже детальный текст. Git понимает, что такое заголовки в комментариях и будет показывать только их в истории. Если вам потребуется подробное описание коммита вы всегда сможете его прочитать.

Ширина детального текста не должна превышать 72 символа. Это называется [форматированием 50/72](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290016/git-commit-messages-50-72-formatting).
На Хабре есть [перевод](https://habr.com/ru/post/416887/) рекомендацией, как писать комментарии.

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю ссылку на конвенцию по написанию [коммитов](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0-beta.4/)

На основе этого соглашения мы для себя решили делить сообщение коммита на три части разделенных пустой строкой:

1. однострочный заголовок со словом характеристикой в начале,
2. многострочный блок пояснений,
3. техническая информация в конце, например номер замечания, задача.

Формализованные тексты коммитов позволяют использовать простые способы парсинга, например, для генерации файла с историей изменений.